# mariabackup loop on "Read redo log up to LSN"

Tags: mariadb, backup

I'm trying to backup my mariadb server environment (master + replica).
I've ran this command:

```
mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/backup/ --user=backup --password=backup --host=192.168.xxx.xxx
```

The command loop on:

```
2023-06-09 13:51:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=1625600
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:10 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:11 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:12 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:13 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:14 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:15 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:16 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:17 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:18 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:19 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:20 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:21 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:22 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:23 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:24 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
2023-06-09 13:51:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=1625600
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:25 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:26 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:27 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:28 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:29 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:30 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:31 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:32 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:33 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:34 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:35 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:36 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:37 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:38 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
[00] 2023-06-09 13:51:39 >> log scanned up to (1625437)
```

I've tried several times, but same result... I'm trying to make a full backup pointing on my replica server.
Server side, with "show processlist" I can see the backup connection on sleep and others connection like:

```
1   system user NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB purge worker NULL    0.000
2   system user NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB purge coordinator    NULL    0.000
3   system user NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB purge worker NULL    0.000
4   system user NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB purge worker NULL    0.000
5   system user NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB shutdown handler NULL    0.000
```

Any ideas to solve? Thanks a lot
Stefano

Comment: I cannot see an existing bug exhibiting this sort of behaviour. Please report a [new bug](https://jira.mariadb.org). Include `show engine innodb status`.

Comment: I've already submitted a new bug on Jira... statement output is too long to paste here...